# ffmpeg geq filter doesn't recognize bitwise operators

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to clamp the lower 6 bits of a [P010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats) (10-bit YUV420 packed in 16b, with data aligned to MSB) video sequence to 0. In C I would do something like:

`pixels_out[y][x] = pixels_in[y][x] & 0xffc0;`

My ffmpeg filter looks like this:

`-vf "geq=lum_expr='lum(X,Y)&0xffc0':cb_expr='cb(X,Y)&0xffc0':cr_expr='cr(X,Y)&0xffc0'"`

ffmpeg is complaining with some error messages:

```
Invalid chars '&0xffc0' at the end of expression 'lum(X,Y)&0xffc0'
Error initializing filter 'geq' with args 'lum_expr=lum(X,Y)&0xffc0:cb_expr=cb(X,Y)&0xffc0:cr_expr=cr(X,Y)&0xffc0'
```

How can I properly mask the bottom 6 bits of the pixel data? Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) filter expressions don't use C syntax. It would be `bitand(lum(X,Y),0xffc0)` However, I'm not sure the filter will operate upon the raw representation, only the MSB 10 bits.

Comment: You are correct, the `bitand` op caused the image to be totally garbled. I ended up writing a C++ program to postprocess the output from ffmpeg and that worked.